# mysql group by partially

Tags: mysql, group-by

Hi I've written this code :

```sql
select `wp_term_taxonomy`.*, count(*)
from `wp_posts`
         inner join `wp_term_relationships` on `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id` = `wp_posts`.`ID`
         inner join `wp_term_taxonomy` on `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id`
where `post_type` = 'product'
  and exists(select *
             from `wp_term_taxonomy`
                      inner join `wp_term_relationships` on `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id`
             where `wp_posts`.`ID` = `wp_term_relationships`.`object_id`
               and `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id` in (401)
               and `taxonomy` = 'product_cat')
  and wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
group by `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id`
```

So here is the result :
[image]

In taxonomy column every value is what I want except pa_shirt_size (at row 22 and 23), for pa_% items I want only one row of each no matter how many they are and which one gets chosen I just want one of each pa_shirt_size and one of pa_shirt_color and ..., basically one of each pa_% in taxonomy.How's this possible? (I don't want to use a seperate query.)

Comment: @Akina Hi thank you for your comment, pa_shirt_size is the value of taxonomy column just look at row 22 and 23 under taxonomy column.I meant to write column not row sorry edited the question thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```
GROUP BY CASE WHEN `wp_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` LIKE 'pa_%' 
              THEN `wp_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` 
              ELSE `wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_taxonomy_id`
              END
```

`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode must be disabled. If not then use ANY_VALUE() or any other aggregate function(s).

[Modelling DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e2c6b25ce2cf0781b4c34b50dd466cf)

Comment: @stevemoretz *It gave the same result back* It is strange... the rows must collapse. *How to use ANY_VALUE() instead?* You must replace an asterisk in output with separate columns list, and wrap each column with this or any other aggregate function (depends on the logic).

Comment: Your last answer was giving the same results back now it just gives the error as expected. [42000][1055] Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'wp_bare.wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: I found the solution thank you you have to use the same case on the select then it won't give an error no more

Comment: @stevemoretz DEMO added.

Comment: Wow this also works pretty cool thank you so much.You're truely master of sql

Comment: @stevemoretz *I found the solution* Post it as self-answer - this may be useful for somebody else.